# MySQL service stops after trying to grant privileges to a user

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, permissions, mysql-5.6, users

I am using MySQL 5.6, I was trying to create a super user for specific database but I got

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'superuser'@'%'
```

Then I thought maybe there is already a user with the same name and password. I flushed privileges and run the following query:

```
grant all privileges on db1.* to 'superuser'@'localhost'
```

After that query I get: `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query`
and MySQL service stops working.

Comment: Did you recently upgrade from MySQL 5.5 ?

Comment: I uninstalled MySQL 5.5 completely before installing MySQL 5.6. I installed it manually though. Do you think it is because of some variable changes?

Comment: Please run this query : `SELECT COUNT(1) column_count FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND table_name='user';` What is column_count ?

Comment: thirty nine (39)

Comment: This is a little messy. I'll explain in my answer ...

Comment: Look at my answer, please. You said 39. That means the `mysql.user` was from MySQL 5.1. EEEEWWW !!!

Comment: Is your datadir `/var/lib/mysql` ?

Comment: I have changed default datadir to D:MySQL files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17785/discussion-between-rolandomysqldba-and-user1722022).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your problem boils down to a misalignment of grants.

When you run this query

```
SELECT COUNT(1) column_count FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND table_name='user';
```

You should the following number

- If you get 43, MySQL 5.6
- If you get 42, MySQL 5.5
- If you get 39, MySQL 5.1
- If you get 37, MySQL 5.0

It simply means you forgot one more upgrade step

```
# mysql_upgrade --upgrade-system-tables
```

This should fill in the missing columns.

I discussed this before

- `May 01, 2013` : [Can I find out what version of MySQL from the data files?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41338/can-i-find-out-what-version-of-mysql-from-the-data-files/41350#41350)
- `Apr 24, 2014` : [mysql: Restore All privileges to admin user (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23276684/491757)

Since you said that `mysql.user` has 39, than means you did not run `mysql_upgrade --upgrade-system-tables` when you went from MySQL 5.1 to MySQL 5.5.

To be honest with you, I do not know if running `mysql_upgrade --upgrade-system-tables` in MySQL 5.6 will successfully realign `mysql.user` two versions back.

I would suggest making a copy by doing the following

```
net stop mysql
cd D:\MySQL\mysql
copy user.frm user1.frm
copy user.MYD user1.MYD
copy user.MYI user1.MYI
net start mysql
```

After making the copy, go ahead and run `mysql_upgrade --upgrade-system-tables`. Login to mysql and run `SELECT COUNT(1) column_count FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND table_name='user';` again. Hopefully it will read 43.

If it does not, copy the user files back like this

```
net stop mysql
cd D:\MySQL\mysql
del user.*
move user1.frm user.frm
move user1.MYD user.MYD
move user1.MYI user.MYI
net start mysql
```

If you want to change the design manually, try the following:

## Create mysql.user_new with MySQL 5.6 layout

```
CREATE TABLE mysql.user_new (
  `Host` char(60) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `User` char(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Password` char(41) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Select_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Insert_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Update_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Delete_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Drop_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Reload_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Shutdown_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Process_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `File_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Grant_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `References_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Index_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Alter_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Show_db_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Super_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_tmp_table_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Lock_tables_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Execute_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Repl_slave_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Repl_client_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_view_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Show_view_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_routine_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Alter_routine_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_user_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Event_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Trigger_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_tablespace_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `ssl_type` enum('','ANY','X509','SPECIFIED') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ssl_cipher` blob NOT NULL,
  `x509_issuer` blob NOT NULL,
  `x509_subject` blob NOT NULL,
  `max_questions` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `max_updates` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `max_connections` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `max_user_connections` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `plugin` char(64) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '',
  `authentication_string` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `password_expired` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Host`,`User`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Users and global privileges';
```

## Move the Grants from Old to New

```
INSERT INTO mysql.user_new
(Host,User,Password,Select_priv,Insert_priv,Update_priv,Delete_priv,
Create_priv,Drop_priv,Reload_priv,Shutdown_priv,Process_priv,File_priv,
Grant_priv,References_priv,Index_priv,Alter_priv,Show_db_priv,Super_priv,
Create_tmp_table_priv,Lock_tables_priv,Execute_priv,Repl_slave_priv,
Repl_client_priv,Create_view_priv,Show_view_priv,Create_routine_priv,
Alter_routine_priv,Create_user_priv,Event_priv,Trigger_priv,ssl_type,
ssl_cipher,x509_issuer,x509_subject,max_questions,
max_updates,max_connections,max_user_connections)
SELECT
Host,User,Password,Select_priv,Insert_priv,Update_priv,Delete_priv,
Create_priv,Drop_priv,Reload_priv,Shutdown_priv,Process_priv,File_priv,
Grant_priv,References_priv,Index_priv,Alter_priv,Show_db_priv,Super_priv,
Create_tmp_table_priv,Lock_tables_priv,Execute_priv,Repl_slave_priv,
Repl_client_priv,Create_view_priv,Show_view_priv,Create_routine_priv,
Alter_routine_priv,Create_user_priv,Event_priv,Trigger_priv,ssl_type,
ssl_cipher,x509_issuer,x509_subject,max_questions,
max_updates,max_connections,max_user_connections
FROM mysql.user;
```

## Update the `Create_tablespace_priv` for `root`

```
UPDATE mysql.user_new SET Create_tablespace_priv='Y' WHERE user = 'root';
```

## Flip the Switch

```
ALTER TABLE mysql.user RENAME mysql.user_old;
ALTER TABLE mysql.user_new RENAME mysql.user;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

## Give it a Try and See if everything works !!!

Comment: Do I need to add those through my.ini file? If thats the case, what variables and values are missing from 5.1 which 5.6 has them?

Comment: BTW MySQL 5.7 has 45 columns in `mysql.user` table and no password column.