# How do I give root@localhost permission to grant privileges in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, permissions

Whenever I try to Grant Privileges as root@localhost, it says permission denied (using password=Yes).

My root user is the one that I am logged in as.   I verify this by select user();

It responds with 'root'@'localhost'.

I have also checked out this stack overflow post which seems to be the same issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796510/cannot-grant-permissions-in-mysql-using-root-or-any-account-access-denied-f

and this one

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server

I am having no luck.  If I Show GRANTS;, It lists all GRANT privileges: SELECT, Insert, Update, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, etc.

1. How do I make sure that ROOT has GRANT option itself?
2. Why would my root user not have all privileges?  I am using mysql version: 5.5.38-0+wheezy1 on Debian.

Comment: A) What command are you running? B) Are you having trouble connecting to the MySQL server or running the command?

Comment: I am running: 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

I am not having trouble connecting to mysql -u root -pMyPassword

Comment: Please run the following query : `select count(1) UserTableColumnCount from information_schema.columns where table_schema='mysql' and table_name='user';`. What number does it report ???

Comment: The output of that command is 39.

Comment: Ah ha. I know the problem. Please stand by ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have dealt with this issue before.

When you ran

```
select count(1) UserTableColumnCount from information_schema.columns
where table_schema='mysql' and table_name='user';
```

you should have gotten 42. That's how many columns MySQL 5.5 has for `mysql.user`. Since you got 39, that means you must have upgraded from MySQL 5.1. That has 39 columns.

I wrote an earlier post about the number of columns in `mysql.user` in different versions : [MySQL service stops after trying to grant privileges to a user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78923/mysql-service-stops-after-trying-to-grant-privileges-to-a-user/78927#78927)

Here is the post where I dealt with this : [mysql: Restore All privileges to admin user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276198/mysql-restore-all-privileges-to-admin-user/23276684#23276684)

Hopefully you could run

```
# mysql_upgrade --upgrade-system-tables
```

to realign `mysql.user` and have it autofill missing permissions with `Y`.

**Give it a Try !!!**

If you want to try to fix the mysql.user manually, here are the steps:

```
#
# Backup the mysql.user table
#
CREATE TABLE mysql.user_backup LIKE mysql.user;
INSERT INTO mysql.user_backup SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
#
# Add Missing Columns
#
ALTER TABLE mysql.user 
    ADD COLUMN Create_tablespace_priv enum('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N'
    AFTER Trigger_Priv
;
ALTER TABLE mysql.user ADD COLUMN plugin char(64);
ALTER TABLE mysql.user ADD COLUMN authentication_string text DEFAULT NULL;
#
# Give root user all privileges
#
UPDATE mysql.user SET
Select_priv='Y',Insert_priv='Y',Update_priv='Y',Delete_priv='Y',
Create_priv='Y',Drop_priv='Y',Reload_priv='Y',Shutdown_priv='Y',
Process_priv='Y',File_priv='Y',Grant_priv='Y',References_priv='Y',
Index_priv='Y',Alter_priv='Y',Show_db_priv='Y',Super_priv='Y',
Create_tmp_table_priv='Y',Lock_tables_priv='Y',Execute_priv='Y',
Repl_slave_priv='Y',Repl_client_priv='Y',Create_view_priv='Y',
Show_view_priv='Y',Create_routine_priv='Y',Alter_routine_priv='Y',
Create_user_priv='Y',Event_priv='Y',Trigger_priv='Y',
Create_tablespace_priv='Y'
WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

That's it !!!

Comment: The --upgrade-system-tables option was used, databases won't be touched.
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed

Comment: Maybe I should downgrade to 5.1.  This is a test server.

Comment: You could add the missing columns manually to mysql.user

Comment: Go to my post http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16397/cannot-grant-privileges-as-root/16441#16441 and see all the columns each version of MySQL has for `mysql.user`

Comment: I just added a manual fix to the `mysql.user` table.

Comment: You, my friend are amazing! I had to log in and log out, but then all is well.

Answer (score 0):

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM 'root'@'localhost'; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'
WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
```

Comment: Is this not risky?  What if it allows me to revoke all fine but still won't allow me to put them back? Is that possible?

Comment: No. Is not. This will grant ALL.

Comment: The privileges will not be activated until you `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`.