# ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'plugin' in 'mysql.user'

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, errors, users, permissions

I am trying to grant privileges for a user to a new database

```
mysql> grant all on db_test.* to 'user_test'@'localhost' identified by 'usersexistingpassword';
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'plugin' in 'mysql.user'
```

I am using MySQL 5.6

```
mysql> select @@version;
+-------------+
| @@version   |
+-------------+
| 5.6.24-72.2 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I did find an article on MySQL on updating Native Passwords on 5.6.x and later

> 6.3.9.3 Migrating Away from Pre-4.1 Password Hashing and the mysql_old_password Plugin
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-upgrades.html

I ran the command they recommend as root

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password'
    -> WHERE plugin = '' AND (Password = '' OR LENGTH(Password) = 41);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'plugin' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem has to do with `mysql.user` and the way you upgraded to MySQL 5.6

If you look my answer to [Cannot GRANT privileges as root](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16397/cannot-grant-privileges-as-root/16441#16441), I show you the description of `mysql.user` from MySQL 4.1 to MySQL 5.6.

The column `plugin` is column #41 in `mysql.user` in MySQL 5.5/5.6

```
mysql> SELECT column_name,ordinal_position FROM information_schema.columns
    -> WHERE table_schema='mysql' and table_name='user' and column_name='plugin';
+-------------+------------------+
| column_name | ordinal_position |
+-------------+------------------+
| plugin      |               41 |
+-------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> SELECT version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.6.24    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql>
```

That column does not appear in MySQL 5.1, 5.0 or 4.x. What this tells me is that somehow MySQL was upgraded to 5.6 but still has the `mysql.user` from 5.1 or older.

If you run `SELECT COUNT(1) column_count FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND table_name='user';` and you get 39, I have just the fix for you.

See my post [MySQL service stops after trying to grant privileges to a user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78923/mysql-service-stops-after-trying-to-grant-privileges-to-a-user/78927#78927) on how manually fix `mysql.user` from 5.1 straight to to 5.6.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar error during `CREATE USER` query.

I did following solution to rectify the user table.

```
ALTER TABLE `user` ADD `Create_tablespace_priv` ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N' AFTER `Trigger_priv`; 
ALTER TABLE `user` ADD `plugin` CHAR(64) NULL AFTER `max_user_connections`; 
ALTER TABLE `user` ADD `authentication_string` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `plugin`; 
ALTER TABLE `user` ADD `password_expired` ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N' AFTER `authentication_string`;
```

Now `CREATE USER` query works fine.!!

Rectification is achieved from the reference of the answer to [Cannot GRANT privileges as root](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16397/cannot-grant-privileges-as-root/16441#16441).
Thank you [RolandoMySQLDBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/877).!

Following helped to create above SQL:

```
+------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field (MySQL 5.1)      | Field (MySQL 5.6)      | Type                              | Null | Key | Default |
+------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+
| Host                   | Host                   | char(60)                          | NO   | PRI |         |
| User                   | User                   | char(16)                          | NO   | PRI |         |
| Password               | Password               | char(41)                          | NO   |     |         |
| Select_priv            | Select_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Insert_priv            | Insert_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Update_priv            | Update_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Delete_priv            | Delete_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Create_priv            | Create_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Drop_priv              | Drop_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Reload_priv            | Reload_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Shutdown_priv          | Shutdown_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Process_priv           | Process_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| File_priv              | File_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Grant_priv             | Grant_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| References_priv        | References_priv        | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Index_priv             | Index_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Alter_priv             | Alter_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Show_db_priv           | Show_db_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Super_priv             | Super_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Create_tmp_table_priv  | Create_tmp_table_priv  | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Lock_tables_priv       | Lock_tables_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Execute_priv           | Execute_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Repl_slave_priv        | Repl_slave_priv        | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Repl_client_priv       | Repl_client_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Create_view_priv       | Create_view_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Show_view_priv         | Show_view_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Create_routine_priv    | Create_routine_priv    | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Alter_routine_priv     | Alter_routine_priv     | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Create_user_priv       | Create_user_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Event_priv             | Event_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| Trigger_priv           | Trigger_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
|                        | Create_tablespace_priv | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
| ssl_type               | ssl_type               | enum('','ANY','X509','SPECIFIED') | NO   |     |         |
| ssl_cipher             | ssl_cipher             | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |
| x509_issuer            | x509_issuer            | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |
| x509_subject           | x509_subject           | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |
| max_questions          | max_questions          | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |
| max_updates            | max_updates            | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |
| max_connections        | max_connections        | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |
| max_user_connections   | max_user_connections   | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |
|                        | plugin                 | char(64)                          | YES  |     |         |
|                        | authentication_string  | text                              | YES  |     | NULL    |
|                        | password_expired       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |
+------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+
```