# Migrating mysql.user table from MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, permissions

I have a tricky question.

- I am migrating from MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 5.6.
- I want to migrate 45 users in MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 5.6

Questions

- Should I just take a dump of the MySQL 5.5 user table and restore on MySQL 5.6 ?
- MySQL 5.6 user table has more columns then MySQL 5.5 so was wondering if that was doable.
- Any other advise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load the mysql schema into the 5.6 instance and [run `mysql_upgrade`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A877%20mysql_upgrade). I have a much cleaner method in mind: You could dump the grants as pure SQL from the MySQL 5.5. instance and then run it in the MySQL 5.6 instance.

You can do one of the following:

- Extract the grants as SQL using [**pt-show-grants**](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-show-grants.html).
- Run my personal emulation of [**pt-show-grants**](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-show-grants.html):

> mysql -u... -p... --AN -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ',QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host),';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" | mysql -u... -p... --skip-column-names -AN | sed 's/$/;/g' > MySQLUserGrants.sql

Once you create the script from the 5.5. instance, run the script in the 5.6 instance.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Note : I have a post where I helped someone manually fix `mysql.user` ([MySQL service stops after trying to grant privileges to a user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78923/mysql-service-stops-after-trying-to-grant-privileges-to-a-user/78927#78927)). Try this only when everything else fails ...